Animation on Scroll with Javascript
I have a <div> that I want to animate from out of the page on the right (overflow: hidden), to slide into the screen on page scroll as the port comes into view. And I want it to slide back out as the port gets out of view. The JS I wrote for it is unbelievably failing.
It's React.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
 export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {

    const section2_2 = document.querySelector(".section2-2");
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      // Animate section2-2 images

      const section2_2Rect = section2_2.getBoundingClientRect();
      const section2_2Top = section2_2Rect.top + window.scrollY;
      const section2_2Bottom = section2_2Rect.bottom + window.scrollY;

      if (
        scrollTop > section2_2Top - window.innerHeight &&
        scrollTop < section2_2Bottom
      ) {
        const images = section2_2.querySelectorAll("img");

        images.forEach((image) => {
          image.style.transition = "right 1s ease-in-out";
          image.style.right = "30%";
        });
      } else {
        const images = section2_2.querySelectorAll("img");

        images.forEach((image) => {
          image.style.right = "130%";
        });
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
return (
    <div>
<div className="section2-2">
          <img
            src={require("../Assets/Images/iPhone_11.webp")}
            alt="iphone"
            className="iphone"
          />
          <img
            src={require("../Assets/Images/iPad_11.webp")}
            alt="ipad"
            className="ipad"
          />
          <img
            src={require("../Assets/Images/Laptop_11.webp")}
            alt="laptop"
            className="laptop"
          />
        </div>
</div>
);
};

